# How to check the url is available in another website from my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to check particular url is available in someone's website from my website?
Ex:
my website is www.example1.com
another url is www.example2.com

I want to check whether the url www.example2.com/blogs is availabe or not from www.example1.come website?

Is it possible? if so can you please let me know how to check?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send an HTTP request to this url using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class and catch exceptions. If the remote server returns 404 you will get an exception when you attempt to download the contents:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.DownloadData("http://www.google.com/x");
        // The url exists
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // 404
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me the example to the above scenario?

Comment: In which method are you performing the test? Is it inside a controller action? If so you could simply let the exception propagate (do not catch it) and the Application_Error of Global.asax will be automatically invoked. Inside this method you could intercept the exception.

Comment: Hi,
Is there any other option to check the url availability in some other website?

Comment: Hi, i want to check the code which are resides in try block with in if condition. is it possible?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. You want to externalize this code in a method taking the url as parameter and returning boolean?